# How to fix duplicate foreign key when adding navigation property to existing relationship?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations, navigation-properties

I have a very simply identity object:

```
Public Class UserRole
    Inherits IdentityUserRole(Of Integer)
End Class
```

By default this generated the following migration:

```
 CreateTable(
    "dbo.UserRoles",
    Function(c) New With
        {
            .UserId = c.Int(nullable := False),
            .RoleId = c.Int(nullable := False)
        }) _
    .PrimaryKey(Function(t) New With { t.UserId, t.RoleId }) _
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", Function(t) t.UserId) _
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Roles", Function(t) t.RoleId) _
    .Index(Function(t) t.UserId) _
    .Index(Function(t) t.RoleId)
```

A foreign key exists to the Roles table, but I did not define a navigation property for UserRole.Role and one does not exist on the object.

When I try to add one:

```
Public Class UserRole
    Inherits IdentityUserRole(Of Integer)

    Public Overridable Property Role() as Role
End Class
```

This generates the following migration:

```
Public Overrides Sub Up()
    AddForeignKey("dbo.UserRoles", "RoleId", "dbo.Roles", "Id")
End Sub
```

And then the site throws an error when trying to migrate:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'FK_dbo.UserRoles_dbo.Roles_RoleId' in the database.
>   Could not create constraint or index.

Why is it trying to generate the foreign key a second time?  Shouldn't it be able to see the existing foreign key from the initial migration?

Is there anything I can do to fix this?